# Passing a PHP data string to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a PHP variable to Ajax which can then be used to return a record/data from a MySQL table.

Background
I have a PHP script that returns data and displays it in rows and columns

```
if($Count2 < $Limit2) {

    if($Coun2 == 0) {
    echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "

    <td  class='roomviewred' title='View reported fault' id='room'  >
        <span class='roomlinktext' >
            <div class='content1'>
               $RoomNo
            </div>
        </span>
    </td>
    ";
    } else {
    $Count = 0;
    echo "
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td  class='roomviewred' title='View reported fault' id='room'>
        <span class='roomlinktext'>
            <div class='content1'>
               $RoomNo
            </div>
        </span>
    </td>
    ";
    }
    $Count++;
}
```

$RoomNo contains a string of data as a 4 digit number. what I need to do is, when either the displayed number of even the containing DIV is clicked
send the data to a jquery/ajax function to send a MySQL request to the data table and return the record associated with the query string.

My jquery/ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var phproom = <?php echo $RoomNo;?>


new jBox('Modal', {
attach: '.roomviewred',
title: 'Reported fault',
theme: 'TooltipBorder',
closeOnClick: 'body',

ajax: {
    url: 'fault_detail.php',
    data: {
       Room: 'phproom'
    },
    reload: 'strict'
    }
});
}
```

The issue I have is when the the on screen room number is click my script is not sending the data to the ajax function. When I view this in 
my browser debugger I see the following:

http://www.example.com/apps/lhr/iframes/fault_detail.php?Room=phproom

what I need to see is the room number in place of "phproom":

http://www.example.com/apps/lhr/iframes/fault_detail.php?Room=0101

If I hard code the room number in the ajax call it works fine so I know I am not passing the data correctly.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Remove `'` around `phproom`?

Comment: Is your JS being loaded as a separate file, or on the same page? I typically strongly discourage mixing PHP echo statements in JS. What you can do is actually to store the `$RoomNo` variable as a cookie (using `$_COOKIE` and then accessing it using JS) or as a HTML5 `data-` attribute of an element in the document, and then reading the value on DOM ready.

Comment: try to print the `phproom ` in console. Check if value is present or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's normal that you get phproom, in your javascript, you define the variable "Room" in data as string 'phproom'.

You need to remove the quote to allow to your program to recognize phproom as variable not as string.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I removed the quotes but still does not work.

Comment: @Nishant Nair Hi, the JS is on the same page. when I print phproom to the console I see nothing.

Comment: try to reorder those lines : 

var phproom = <?php echo $RoomNo;?>

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: hi, when you say reorder "$(document).ready(function() {" what do you mean?

Comment: hi, the line [var phproom = <?php echo $RoomNo;?>] must be the first, and followed by [$(document).ready(function() {]

Comment: Hi and sorry to be a pain. I have reordered the code but still does not work

var phproom = <?php echo $RoomNo2;?>

$(document).ready(function() {

 new jBox('Modal', {
 attach: '.roomviewred',
 title: 'Reported fault',
 theme: 'TooltipBorder',
 closeOnClick: 'body',

 ajax: {
     url: 'fault_detail.php',
     data: {
         Room: phproom
     },
     reload: 'strict'
     }
 });

Comment: If I change Room: phproom without the quotes around phproom the ajax part of the script fails. Any ideas?

Comment: this parts of code (PHP and Javascript) are in the same page ?

Comment: Hi, yes both the php and the jquery/ajax are on the same page. What should happen is when a room number is click the underlying number should get passed to the ajax query, return the data from the table and display the data in "fault_detail.php" which is inside the jquery modal window popup,

Comment: hello try the code in this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/qua9e06h7xwxkcy/code.txt?dl=0

I added some comments to explain you the changes

Comment: hi and thanks for getting back to me. I have the code you kindly provided but when I click on a room number nothing happens. Viewing this in the browser debugger I see no errors even when I step through each process. I think it must be somthing to do with the clicking on the room number, what do you think?

Comment: Hi, I now have this working perfectly but only with your help. Many thanks for all your time.